# Flash in firefox does not start unitl they show in page

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, flash

I have this little problem.
My client wanted two distinct swf on a web page: a viewer on top and a slideshow of images at bottom. 
Clicking a link on the slideshow make the viewer load a movie, by means of LocalConnection api.

The slideshow has a default, so when the page is loaded a default movie start.

This works nice on all browser. The only problem I have is on firefox. When screen resolution is too low, or the monitor is too small (netbook) the slideshow remain hidden until scrolling. Therefore at page loading it doesn't start and the main viewer don't get instructed on playing the default video.

As soon as I scroll the page, and the slideshow swf display on page, it starts and everything works fine.

Do you know if there are any solution to this ?

I cannot change the design, I must have two distinct swf, they come from a library he has, and I am trying to reuse components.

thanks
Leonardo

Comment: Perhaps showing your swf behind a visible div as 1x1 pixel so it gets loaded and then place it where it should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show at least 1px of the swf. AFAIK this is the only way to load swf in FF 3.6+

Comment: This strange behaviour seems to happen only on Windows XP FF 3.6. Mac osx behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the default always the same? You could have some error handling in the slideshow that would load the default if the connection is not there or the slideshow to load is undefined. It's a guess but it might solve your first run issue.